# Macro with Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library Compatibility with Microsoft Excel 14.0

Tags: vba, excel, object, ms-word

I wrote a macro in Word that uses the Excel object. To enable this, I referenced the Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library, but now my coworkers with the 14.0 library are getting errors like "Compile Error: Can’t find Project or library" when they initially run the macro and "Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library" when they enable the 14.0 library.

Is my macro compatible with the 14.0 library? If not, is there any way I can make it compatible?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you go to references you will notice it will say MISSING: reference for the library in question.

Just untick it(your co-worker) and it should pick up the current library.

To resolve I'd use the old library if you have an environment where you operate multiple versions of office.